# Ionic local Notifications based on selected and saved date and time in localstorage

Tags: json, ionic-framework, local-storage, localnotification

I am trying to configure local notification in my ionic app using `cordova-plugin-local-notification`. But it is not working.

Please suggest where i am doing the mistake.

Now i am using the below query to set the notification.

```
localStorage.setItem("notifytime", "3600");
    var notiftime = localStorage.getItem("notifytime");
    this.localNotifications.schedule({
      text: 'Delayed ILocalNotification',
      trigger: {at: new Date(new Date().getTime() + notiftime)},
      led: 'FF0000',
      sound: null
   });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the `notiftime` variable to int before:

```
var notiftime = localStorage.getItem("notifytime");
var time = parseInt(notiftime);
new Date(new Date().getTime() + time);
```